# Showing Page Timeline on public website

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp-classic

I am trying to create a public website, which shows the last 5 timeline posts from various Facebook Pages.

I am using the Facebook Graph API to request JSON and a JSON parser (www.aspjson.com) to read the JSON with ASP Classic.

The code I've worked out so far is pretty simple:

```
<!--#include file="scripts/aspJSON1.12.asp"-->
<%

response.codepage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8"

function EncodingFixer(str)
  EncodingFixer = replace(str, "u00e5", "&aring;")
  EncodingFixer = replace(EncodingFixer, "u00e6", "&aelig;")
  EncodingFixer = replace(EncodingFixer, "u00f8", "&oslash;")
end function

sub FacebookAPI()
  set objHTTP = createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  objHTTP.Open "GET", Location, false
  objHTTP.Send

  set oJSON = new aspJSON
  oJSON.loadJSON(objHTTP.responsetext)

  set ItemList = oJSON.data("data")

  for each Item in ItemList
    PostDate = formatdatetime(left(ItemList.item(Item).item("created_time"), 10), 2)
    Message = EncodingFixer(ItemList.item(Item).item("message"))
    response.write "<br /><strong>" & PostDate & "</strong><br />" & Message & "<br />"
  next
end sub

Location = "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=created_time,message,comments,likes&limit=5&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"
call FacebookAPI()

%>
```

My problem is this: I am creating the token inside the Graph API Explorer, and after a little time, it expires.
I cant find a working example on creating an access token, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tokens are short-lived, only lasting two hours. You need to get yourself a page access token that doesn't expire under scenario 5 of https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

> By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?
    access_token=EXTENDED_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

or

`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&access_token=EXTENDED_ACCESS_TOKEN`

> will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages.

The page token will not have an expiration.

See a full example in PHP at http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/getting-your-facebook-page-on-your-website-with-access-tokens/